# Number of binary matrices

Tags: combinatorics, matrices

Given $N,M$ device an algorithm to find how many binary matrices exist where all $0$s form a connected component, i.e., from any $0$, you can reach to all $0$s. Two cells are adjacent when they share a side.

For ex.: $N=M=2$, there are total of 16 matrices. Out of which two will get removed, which consist of placing $0$s on diagonals. So total = $14$ matrices.

Comment: Is this homework ? Or is it part of a research/project ? I would be amazed if there is a "simple" solution to that.

Comment: Connected in the sense of $4$ directions or $8$ directions?

Comment: 4-directions i.e must share a side.

Comment: @maverick: Do you have any reason to believe there's a simple answer?

Comment: I have already thought of something in n^4 dp. I believe something better will exist.

Comment: @maverick: So you're looking for an algorithm to accomplish the count, not necessarily a formula. Yes?

Comment: Consider the matrix to be a graph and use some Depth/Breadth-First-Search from a $0$. Then if after termination of the search, there still remains some $0$ that are not included in the result of the search, then it means there are at least two $0$-connected components.

Comment: @quasi yes, an algorithm.